# Is it normal to create 2 unrelated(different) resources in one request?

Tags: rest, api, web

When a user offers friendship to another user, he automatically subscribes to him. How to implement this in REST Api?
2 different entities(aggregates) are created in one request: Friendship (with OFFERED status) and Subscription, but the endpoint is called /friendships. Is it normal that there is such a side effect as a subscription? Or should I implement it differently?
Are there recommendations for such situations?

I want the logic to remain the same: automatic subscription occurs when a friendship is offered. Not otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, adding a subscription when adding a friendship is your own application logic (which can be changed in future based on how yours users like it). It has nothing to do with the endpoint and /friendships is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Today I also came to this conclusion. Your answer dispelled the remaining doubts